# How to setup listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Ok here's a noob question. How would I set up a listview that when clicked brings up a description preferably on a new page. As of now the app only opens up and displays a menu and every time the title section is changed it changes the pages number.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
    actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
            // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
            new ArrayAdapter(
                    actionBar.getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    new String[]{
                            getString(R.string.title_section1),
                            getString(R.string.title_section2),
                            getString(R.string.title_section3),
                            getString(R.string.title_section4),
                    }),
            this);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM,
            getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
    // When the given tab is selected, show the tab contents in the container
    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit();
    return true;
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return textView;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't have nothing implemented yet I suggest you to start by a default adapter implementation.

Check [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listview_overview) out, it will help you.

**EDIT:**

First of all, you must add a `ListView` view to your *activity_main.xml* file.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

After this you are able to access the list that means you can fill it with some items.

1. "Find your `View`"

   ```
   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList)
   ```
2. Define data array to bind and set the adapter
   (I'm going to use the same array from the example)

   ```
   final String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
   "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
   "Linux", "OS/2" }; // You have the necessary data to bind the list.

   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values); // You have set     the previous array to an adapter that can be now setted to a list.

   listView.setAdapter(adapter); //Set adapter and that's it.
   ```

Well, this an easy way to start understanding how to fill list views. If you want a list item to have more than single text than you have to build your own custom adapter class. But that would be subject to another question :D

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks I favorited the page, but I still need help on what to do.